# Check my code, I‘m using ThreadLocal to manage HttpSession

Tags: java, web, httpsession

I'm use ThreadLocal to manage HttpSession. code as below:

```
public class HttpSessionLocal {

    private static ThreadLocal<HttpSession> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<HttpSession>();

    public static HttpSession getSession(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = threadLocal.get();
        if (session == null) {
            threadLocal.set(request.getSession());
        }
        return threadLocal.get();
    }

    public static void setSession(HttpSession session) {
        threadLocal.set(session);
    }

}


public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        HttpSessionLocal.setSession(null);
    }
}
```

**Can we do this? If not, how can we improve it? Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no sense. `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` returns the same `HttpSession` object for all requests within the same session. You don't need to cache it. Besides, `HttpSession` is not thread bound, requests within the same session may come in different threads.

Comment: actually I have got a problem， that  one user found his username is another people when he was login in website. But I have save the user information in httpsession. I think the session is mixed up, but the frequency is very low. So I decided to use Threadlocal to management httpsession.

Answer (score 0):

You're code will not work as intended as the http request thread is different than the thread spawn by the container to deal with the `sessionDestroyed` event.

I can't imagine why you keep the http session in a thread local and require the `HttpServletRequest` as argument to the `HttpSessionLocal.getSession`. If you have a reference to the `request` you can get the http session with: `request.getSession()`.

Comment: actually I have got a problem， that  one user found his username is another people when he was login in website. But I have save the user information in httpsession. I think the session is mixed up. So I decided to use Threadlocal to management httpsession.